# How do I make my function work when I move it to a shared function class?

Tags: java, android

I want to open a web page from multiple location within my app. This is the function that works fine when I call it from within the same class where it resides.

```
public void inLineShowWebPage() {

    String url = "https://www.google.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        try {
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d ("myError", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I don't want to copy the above code to every activity in my app so I set up a shared functions activity as shown below.

```
public class SharedFunctions extends AppCompatActivity {

public void showWebPage() {

    String url = "https://www.google.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    try {
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d ("myError", e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

and call it like this:

```
SharedFunctions sf = new SharedFunctions();
sf.showWebPage();
```

This results in the error message:

**myError:** `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference`

When I go into debug mode, I can see that i is not null. I'd appreciate any help as I've been trying to solve this problem for about 4 hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need activity context to call `startActivity()`. Pass activity context while calling the function and use activity's context to call `startActivity()`. Change your code as below and try.

```
public void showWebPage(Context mContext) {

    String url = "https://www.google.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    try {
        mContext.startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d ("myError", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Also no need to extend your **SharedFunction** class from `AppCompatActivity`, Remove the extend and declare it as standalone class.

Comment: That has solved the problem. Thanks for your prompt reply.